# Understanding latitudes longitudes and angles

Tags: latitude-longitude, angles, vincenty-formulae

I am very new to geographic concepts.

I already know and understand the concepts of latitude and longitude.

What I am trying to find is the angle between two points having those points data.

First I found [this method in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424986/4451521) so I paste that in a script.

But also I am aware (very shallowly) of the Vicenty inverse function as implemented in [here](https://qiita.com/r-fuji/items/99ca549b963cedc106ab) (Sorry the text is in Japanese but the code is there and also it can be read with browsers translation addons).

Anyway, I put those into a script and I calculated the angle and I got

```
lat1=35.8761982
lon1=139.8928402
lat2=35.8761819
lon2=139.8929373
```

For the first function:

```
angle: 123.93465391546005
```

For the second method

```
{'distance': 8.953134933413606, 'azimuth1': 101.65430860803279, 'azimuth2': 281.65436551444265}
```

So my question is, what is `azimuth1` and `azimuth2` calculating? (because in a map I can see that an angle of 123.9 seems correct...)

EDIT1: I checked it with https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle
and it seems the angle (or bearing??) is close to 101.704 degrees)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azimuth is a term that is commonly used in navigation and is defined as the angle measured clockwise from a reference direction (usually north) to the direction of an object. Azimuth1 and azimuth2 would be two different azimuth measurements. The exact meaning of these terms would depend on the context in which they are used. For example, if someone were discussing the orientation of a satellite dish, azimuth1 and azimuth2 could refer to the horizontal angle of the dish relative to true north at two different times. Alternatively, if someone were discussing the direction of two different objects in the sky, azimuth1 and azimuth2 could refer to the horizontal angle of each object relative to true north.

In this context, it seems that azimuth1 and azimuth2 are the angles measured clockwise from north to the direction of the two points with latitude and longitude.

Comment: Thanks! I ve tried it with https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle and it seems the answer in SO was wrong, and the vincenty calculation was closer.